# Недопонимание с функцией pthread_create()

Tags: c, многопоточность

Есть функция `pthread_create()`, шаблон которой выглядит так:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *pth, pthread_attr_t *att, void * (*function)(void *), void *arg);
```

И у меня есть некоторые вопросы по этой функции:

1) Вызов функции в разных источниках выглядит по-разному, какой правильный и есть ли вообще разница?

```
void * fun(void *arg){
    int count = * (int *)arg;
    printf("Thread %d\n", count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int count = 1;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, fun, &count); // первый способ
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &fun, &count); // второй способ

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

2) Почему, когда мы передаем функции `pthread_create()` функцию `fun()`, то мы не передаем ей никакого аргумента? Вместо этого, я где-то читал, что функции `fun()` передается четвертый аргумент функции `pthread_create()`, однако как это делается - я не понимаю

3) Функция `pthread_create()` первым аргументом принимает указатель на `pthread_t *`, это сделано с целью экономии памяти и т.д или потому-что адрес играет какую то роль? Просто код ниже доказывает, что адрес не играет роли:

```
void * fun(void *arg){
        int count = * (int *)arg;
        printf("Thread %d\n", count);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int *status;
    while(i < 10){
        pthread_t thread;
        status = malloc(1);
        *status = i++;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, fun, (void *)status);
        printf("%ld\n", thread);

}
```

Здесь создается `10` потоков, а адрес у `thread` не изменяется.

Comment: Указатель на функцию можно передавать как `fun`, так и `&fun` (в данном случае разницы нет). Вызов `fun` где-то внутри `int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,  void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)` уже в новом потоке  записывается вот так: `start_routine(arg);`

Comment: Точнее, конечно же, сам вызов осуществляется уже в системном вызове [clone](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone)

Comment: Кстати, ваш пример с созданием потоков в цикле не совсем корректный, `malloc` надо бы вызывать не с 1, а с `sizeof(int)` (да, в стандартных реализациях в обеих случаях будет выделяться достаточно памяти (скорее всего 16 (может 8) байт))

Comment: @avp так у меня status имеет тип int, разве автоматически не будет умножаться на размер типа?

Comment: [никто ничего домножать не будет](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> шаблон которой выглядит так:
>   это называется сигнатура

1) в случае си оба варианта нормальны (насколько я помню).

2) в pthread_create передается адрес функции. Поэтому, там нет скобок. Были бы скобки - функция вызывалась бы. pthread_create создает собственно поток (это спрятано в недрах операционной системы. И потом делает переход на функцию, которая ей была передана как аргумент. А также аккуратно в стек вкладывает параметр.

3) согласно документации

> On success, pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error
>          number, and the contents of *thread are undefined.

В принципе, функция могла бы возвращать и pthread_t, но тут возникает много проблем. К примеру, как проверять создался или нет поток, что делать с переменной pthread_t, когда поток завершится - вызывать ли функцию для очистки. И много других проблем. В таких языках как питон, можно возвратить кортеж из двух значений, а в си нужно было бы возвращать указатель на структуру, а потом чистить память.

Но возникает вопрос, а зачем эта переменная (типа pthread_t)? а это та ручка, которая позволят управлять потоком. Другие функции работы с потоком принимают эту переменную как аргумент. Например, pthread_join, что бы подождать выполнения.

В Вашем случае "оно не имеет значения", потому что Вы создаете треды и просто отпускаете их в вольное плаванье.